# Android: Finish activity with class name

Tags: android

My app has a button that act as the back button on android. However it appears on top of any other applications, I want the user to press on the "back button" i.e. my custom back button in order to close the current activity. I can get the current activity name and so my question is how do I finish an activity with only the class name? Thanks

Comment: Why implement your own back button when Android already has one?  This is not good usability.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is not clear, but I think all you want to do is close the current activity when you click a button so that you go back to the previous activity. Add the following click listener to your back button

```
  new View.OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(View view) {

           MyActivityName.this.finish();

       }
  }
```

Comment: Actually I am doing that in a service, where I can't call finish. And I can only get the activity name of the running activity, which is the one I want to close when the user clicks the custom back button

Comment: In that case, I've just written an answer for another question I think should be relevant, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351974/how-to-perform-back-button-action-in-another-app/21352046#21352046

Comment: You should pay attention to simons comment above which I've upvoted. This seems like a bad usecase anyway, so you might be approaching the problem the wrong way

Comment: However I want to close other third parties apps, how can I achieve that? And actually I am developing an app that has different controls on floating over other apps, including a back button, that's why I am asking how can I close a running activity

Answer (score 0):

This my scenario

A-> B->C

When c got success I want again come to A if user pressed back button then dont want A I want B

In that case I took on static boolean variable if set true flag on C after successful transaction if user press back then false.

on B I check on

```
@Override
protected void onRestart() {

    if (isSuccessfully) {
        finish();
    }
    super.onRestart();

}
```